# Python3: Trying to concatenate two dataframes timeseries with differing datetime index column types

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, indexing, concatenation

**Summary of the Problem:**
*The index column for both dataframes is of a different type and python does not know how to concatenate both.*

Disclaimer:
I am a beginner in python.

Hey guys,

I want to concatenate 2 dataframes from two different data providers 
df_1: Alpha Vantage and 
df_2: Quandl.

df_1 looks like:

```
                 PG    ^GSPC
2000-01-03  32.0022  1455.22
2000-01-04  31.3753  1399.42
2000-01-05  31.1066  1402.11
2000-01-06  32.2112  1403.45
2000-01-07  34.7785  1441.47
[...]
2019-07-11  114.38  2999.9099
2019-07-12  114.99  3013.7700
2019-07-15  115.48  3014.3000
2019-07-16  115.89  3004.0400
2019-07-17  115.74  2992.0200
```

df_2 looks like:

```
            10 YR
Date             
1990-01-02   7.94
1990-01-03   7.99
1990-01-04   7.98
1990-01-05   7.99
1990-01-08   8.02
[...]
2019-07-10   2.07
2019-07-11   2.13
2019-07-12   2.12
2019-07-15   2.09
2019-07-16   2.13
```

However, when i concatenate using this

```
xyz = pd.concat((df_1 , df_2 ), axis=1, sort = False)
```

I get a Dataframe that looks like that:

```
                 PG         ^GSPC     10 YR
2000-01-03      32.0022     1455.2200   NaN
2000-01-04      31.3753     1399.4200   NaN
2000-01-05      31.1066     1402.1100   NaN
2000-01-06      32.2112     1403.4500   NaN
2000-01-07      34.7785     1441.4700   NaN
2000-01-10      34.5994     1457.6000   NaN
2000-01-11      35.1666     1438.5601   NaN
2000-01-12      34.9278     1432.2500   NaN
2000-01-13      34.3307     1449.6801   NaN
2000-01-14      34.9278     1465.1500   NaN
2000-01-18      34.8979     1455.1400   NaN
[...]
2019-07-05 00:00:00     NaN         NaN     2.04
2019-07-08 00:00:00     NaN         NaN     2.05
2019-07-09 00:00:00     NaN         NaN     2.07
2019-07-10 00:00:00     NaN         NaN     2.07
2019-07-11 00:00:00     NaN         NaN     2.13
2019-07-12 00:00:00     NaN         NaN     2.12
2019-07-15 00:00:00     NaN         NaN     2.09
2019-07-16 00:00:00     NaN         NaN     2.13
```

So the index column for both dataframes is of a different type and python does not know how to concatenate both, instead it just stacks them on top of each other. My question is, how do I change the index column type so that python can properly concatenate?

Note:

i) I previously concatenated df_1 from two dataframes with out issues:

```
df_1 = pd.concat([stock['5. adjusted close'], indx['5. adjusted close']], axis = 1, sort = False)
df_1 .columns = [userin_stock, userin_indx]     # Renaming columns
df_1 = df_1 [np.isfinite(df_1 [userin_indx])]  # Checking for NaN values and dropping those rows
```

ii) I transformed df_2 from series to dataframe using this command

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame([df_2 ])

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

iii) df_2 changed 
Previously i tried to change the datetime frequency from T to D, which I thought fixed the problem. However once I concat, the 00:00:00 reapeared.

```
df_2= df_2.resample('D', how='mean')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) will simply stack your two dataframes onto each other.

What you want to do is use [`Join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) instead.

```
result = df_1.join(df_2)
```

This will join `df_1` with `df_2` on the index column.

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem for me :)
Do you have any recommendation where I can read up on the differences about concat, merge, join, etc? Because Im confused how concat worked before and now it doesnt.
Thank you again :)